# killing subprocesses and traps

Tags: process, kill, signals, trap

I have the following two scripts which simulate some work:

`start.sh` simply launches 2 (mpi) processes with script `mpiproc.sh`.

**start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

function trap_with_arg() {
    func="$1" ; shift
    for sig ; do
        trap "$func $sig" "$sig"
    done
}

function handleSignal() {
    echo "Received signal (sleep for 10 sec)"
    for i in {1..2}
    do
      echo "start.sh: sleeping $i"
      sleep 1s
    done
    exit 0
}

# Setup the Trap
trap_with_arg handleSignal SIGINT SIGTERM SIGUSR1 SIGUSR2

mpirun -n 2 mpiproc.sh
```

**mpiproc.sh**

```
function trap_with_arg() {
    func="$1" ; shift
    for sig ; do
        trap "$func $sig" "$sig"
    done
}


function handleSignal() {
    echo "Rank: ${OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK} : Received signal (sleep for 10 sec)"
    for i in {1..10}
    do
      echo "Rank: ${OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK} sleeping $i"
      sleep 1s
    done
    exit 0
}

# Setup the Trap
trap_with_arg handleSignal SIGINT SIGTERM SIGUSR1 SIGUSR2

echo "MPI Proc  Rank: ${OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK} start."
sleep 30s
```

The cluster I am running the script `start.sh` sends a SIGUSR2 signal to start.sh (thats what I think). The problem is that my `handleSignal` in mpiproc does not finish because start.sh already executed its `handleSignal` and calles `exit 0`.
How can I make the handleSignal calls travel up the process tree? Meaning first mpiproc.sh needs to handle the signal (start.sh somehow waits on that?) and then start.sh does the cleanup and then exits?

Thanks!